# How can I keep user into the session

Tags: python, flask

```
user=users.query.filter(db.and_(users.username ==  request.form['username'] ,users.password==request.form['password'])).first()
```

I've already tried

```
app.config['user'] = user and session['user']=user
```

,but it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few glaring issues with your approach here. Be sure to read Flask documentation on handling sessions first, which gives you a really nice example to play with:

http://flask.pocoo.org/quickstart/#sessions

```py
from flask import Flask, session, redirect, url_for, escape, request
from werkzeug.security import check_password_hash

app = Flask(__name__)

app.secret_key = b'_5#y2L"F4Q8z\n\xec]/'

def get_session_user():
    if 'username' not in session:
        return None
    username = session['username']
    # fetch the user from database somehow
    user = db.get_user_by_username(username)
    return user

def verify_password(hashed: str, password: str) -> bool:
    return check_password_hash(hashed, password)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    user = get_session_user()
    if user:
        return f'You are logged in as {user.username}'
    return f'Please <a href="/login">login</a>'

@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.form['username']
        password = request.form['password']
        user = db.get_user_by_username(username)
        
        if not user:
            return 'No such user'
        
        # hopefully you're storing hashed passwords in DB
        # you need to check if the credentials matches what's stored in DB
        if not verify_password(user.hashed_password, password):
            return 'Invalid credentials'
        
        session['username'] = user.username
        return redirect('/')
    
    return '''
        <form method="post">
            <input name='username' placeholder='username'>
            <input type='password' name='password' placeholder='password'>
            <button>Login</button>
        </form>
    '''

@app.route('/logout')
def logout():
    session.pop('username', None)
    return redirect('/')
```

Comment: I've seen this,but it coundn't help me
When I want to add picture  into profile page,I must keep user into the session and call,but I can't do it

Comment: Once you query `user` from DB, you need to store user id in session `session['user_id'] = user.id`. Then when you need to access the user info, you retrieve `user_id` back from the session `user_id = session['user_id']` and query the user back from DB, and use the model instance as you like.

Comment: post=posts(title=request.form['title'],content=request.form['content'],image=filename,user=app.config['user'])
I used this for relation,in that case I don't want to keep only Id ,I want to keep object

Comment: Storing large objects in session is rarely a good idea, because exchanging large blobs of cookie back and forth between client <-> server slows down operations. Instead keep only what you need to identify user, not more.

Comment: I've updated my post to reflect your use case a bit more, modify it to suit your needs